# MySql - Type of concurrency issues

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions

I know that the the "Dirty Reads" occurs when a transaction selects data that hasn't been committed by another transaction. For example, transaction A changes a row. Transaction B then selects the changed row before transaction A commits the change.
If transaction A then rolls back the change, transaction B has selected data
that doesn't exist in the database.

If we resolve this problem, it means that MySql lock selected data, but should this automatically resolve also the "Lost updates" and "Nonrepeatable reads" problems ?

Lost Updates = Occur when two transactions select the same row and then update the row based on the values originally selected.

Nonrepeatable reads = Occur when two SELECT statements that try to get the same data get different values because another transaction has updated the data in the time between the two statements.

Comment: To get rid of dirty reads, you only need to set the isolation level to `Read Committed`, but this will still allow for nonrepeatable reads. That's how the isolation levels are defined, see e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)#Isolation_levels,_read_phenomena,_and_locks). I'm not sure if you are wondering why that does not include higher isolation levels. In that case, rethink the part "it means that MySql lock selected data" (which is technically not correct if taken literally, but might also just be an unprecise/vague expression).

Comment: "Lost Updates" are fixed by using `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` when you are going to update afterwards. This acquires the exclusive locks on the rows when you select them instead of waiting until the update.